# Custom aggregate annotation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have many groups which each has a revision and each revision has some months.

I want to output all the group objects with an annotation.

For each group it should only select the latest revision and then sum all the months.

I'm not sure if it can be done in Django. I tried something like

```
Group.objects.annotate(
    month_sum=Revision.objects.filter(date__lte=my_date).latest('date').aggregate(Sum('months__amount'))
)
```

and hoped to get a queryset with all groups which each has a sum `month_sum`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one:

```
qs = Group.objects.filter(revision__date__lte=my_date).annotate(month_sum=Sum('months__amount'))
```

You can debug and try to undestand how to make the right query by printing the generated DB query in the shell:

```
print str(qs.query)
```

**Edit:**

To show even Groups with old revision I think [django-aggregate-if](https://github.com/henriquebastos/django-aggregate-if/) may help you

Run `pip install django-aggregate-if`

```
from django.db.models import Q
from aggregate_if import Sum

revision = Revision.objects.filter(revision__date__lte=my_date).latest()
qs = Group.objects.all().annotate(month_sum=Sum('months__amount', only=Q(revision=revision)))
```

Comment: It's great. The problem is that I only want the latest revision and not all revisions so I need to do something like `filter(revision_date_lte=my_date).latest()`

Comment: I'm so close to make it work I think. It seems to work but only for one group. I guess it's because each groups has some estimates and each estimate has some revisions. With your example it will filter for the same revision in each group. I really don't think how to solve it but I appreciate your help! `django-aggregate-if` should be implemented in Django :-D